# When would you want to run an NSURLConnection on a secondary thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

We're writing an SDK which heavily uses NSURLConnection. To manage all these connections (e.g., to mass-cancel them), it would be best if they all run on a single thread (preferably the main thread). Due to the asynchronous nature of NSURLConnection, this is not a terrible idea - in our standalone application, all our connections run on the main thread, and the heavy lifting is performed on secondary threads (actually, using GCD or operation queues) after the connection results are obtained, and nothing stalls.

So the question is - in which cases would users want to run connections on more than one thread, and on a thread which is not the main thread?

EDIT: I think I didn't explain myself properly. We're using NSURLConnection in an **asynchronous**, not synchronous, fashion. This allows us to run all connections on the main thread without blocking the UI. The question is: when would a user of our SDK wish to run these connections both asynchronously and on a different thread?

Comment: Use [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). It has properties to [cancel the operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/cancelAllOperations).

Comment: Doesn't each `NSURLConnection` run on a background thread?

Comment: The sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error method blocks the thread calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only good reason I can imagine for running an asynchronous NSURLConnection on another thread is if your delegate methods are themselves very time intensive. Even then, I would likely still run it on the main thread, and just move the processing onto a background queue.

EDIT: Note that today "move the processing onto a background thread" is very easy. Prior to GCD, this was a little harder, and so running the NSURLConnection itself on a secondary thread could be more useful in that case. It is also still somewhat useful when you embed an NSURLConnection into a C++ app which does not process a runloop on the main thread (this basically applies only to Mac apps).

As I believe you understand, NSURLConnection already manages its own background thread for its internal use.

In short, I believe your intuition around this is correct. The answer is "almost never." NSURLConnection is most easily managed on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'd like to wait a little while for dissenting opinion. If it doesn't exist, I'll accept your answer :-)

Comment: Mmm, do you want to share them? :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you have a request which loads a lot of data and you are sure that it will be slow, and you have a GUI that needs to be rendered frequently.
This case if the GUI (like in Cocoa, the GUI is updated in the main thread) is updated in the main thread, having a request which is too slow may cause all the views to stop showing, because they're not updated.

Also Apple documentation says this about sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error :

*Important: Because this call can potentially take several minutes to fail (particularly when using a cellular network in iOS), you should never call this function from the main thread of a GUI application.*

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I believe there's been a misunderstanding - please see my edit.

Comment: So you're calling it from another thread.If this thread does important things and you don't want to block it, you use an asynchronous request.